# I literally got STUCK in Dear Esther - how do I get "unstuck"?

Tags: source-engine, dear-esther

Just 30 minutes into the game I try to walk onto a rooftop for some reason... I promptly got stuck and literally can't move an inch. It's as if my walk buttons are disabled. **Is there any way to get unstuck in this game, or will I have to start all over?**

Note: this game is based on Valve's Source engine. Development console is enabled in the options, but I can't seem to manage to open it. It doesn't open when clicking the § key as it does in other Source games, nor while holding shift or control and clicking it.

---

I've restarted the chapter and walked onto the edge of the roof again, and yep, I got stuck. So it seems there's a bug a 5 minute walk into chapter 2 near the rooftop of a house where you get stuck. [Here's a picture of the scene](http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/504639010035603659/55A1520C1A10BF694147807610031CE4D552F8E6/) and above is a link to the game saves if somebody has trouble finding the spot. Hope it gets fixed! Also a configurable key-bind for the developer console would have saved me hours of frustration. I still can't open it.

Comment: @AshleyNunn: Why edit away the source-engine label? It's kinda relevant to the question

Comment: There were a lot of bugs like this in the 2008 mod, but they were supposed to be fixed in the new version...

Comment: @Codemonkey I didn't intend to. I will put it back.

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/504639010035603659/55A1520C1A10BF694147807610031CE4D552F8E6/) of the scene I'm stuck in... Don't know if it helps

Comment: This is probably a question best addressed to the developers :\

Comment: I have restarted the chapter and made a backup of the quicksave in which I'm stuck by the roof. That way I can test any future solutions posted here and still continue the game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the config file and change `toggleconsole` to any key (I used "-"). Save the file, then right click on it, choose Properties, and set as read only. When in game, open the console and type `sv_cheats 1`, then `noclip 1`. Close the console, get out of where you were stuck, open the console again and type `noclip 0`. Worked for me!

Comment: I guess this answer is *probably* the correct answer, even though it was impossible for me to open the console. I ended up restarting the level instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use the console command `~` and type `load autosave`. Dear Esther seems fond of her save files, so hopefully you should be able to return to a point prior without to much hassle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I can't seem to get the console open. It's enabled in the options, but I think I've tried every button on the keyboard without success. I'm using a Norwegian keyboard, and to make a ~ symbol I have to hold CTRL+ALT and press the ¨ key. That key combination didn't work in the game. Is there a configuration file or something in which I can set the developer console key-bind? Any other advice?

Comment: I have found the configuration file in which `bind "\`" "toggleconsole"` appears. I've tried changing the key it binds to, but it resets to "\`" every time the game launches or exits. This is starting to get incredibly frustrating since there is no "` key" on my keyboard.

Comment: Well, if you're using Windows, you can load up the On-Screen Keyboard. Display Esther in a window rather than fullscreen, then use the On-Screen Keyboard to hit the "`" key.

EDIT: You could also check to ensure that the configuration file isn't set to read-only.

Comment: Good idea. I am now utterly convinced that the console cannot in fact be opened. I've tried to use the on-screen keyboard to press \` and ~ and all CTRL, ALT and SHIFT combinations of them. I've also tried to change the language of my keyboard so that \` and ~ is on the key above TAB, and still the console is impossible to open. I think it might just be completely disabled in Dear Esther

Comment: It's not, because that's how I reloaded my game when movement was disabled after a swim in the water.

Answer (score 0):

Editing TOGGLECONSOLE in the config file actually works. The properties HAS to be set to "read only" before starting the game. If not the file is reset to default.

I changed TOGGLECONSOLE to - and it worked out just fine. Sadly the following commands sv_cheats and noclip 1 didn't work. I mean, they were recognized by the console but didn't change anything in the game.